# Select everything that has only one value in a relation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Okay, so here are my tables:
tests:

```
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | test-one   |
|  2 | test-two   |
|  3 | test-three |
|  4 | test-four  |
|  5 | test-five  |
|  6 | test-six   |
+----+------------+
```

testGroups:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | group-one   |
|  2 | group-two   |
|  3 | group-three |
|  4 | group-four  |
|  5 | group-five  |
|  6 | group-six   |
|  7 | group-seven |
|  8 | group-eight |
|  9 | group-nine  |
| 10 | group-ten   |
+----+-------------+
```

and testGroupAssignments

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | testID | groupID |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      1 |       1 |
|  2 |      2 |       1 |
|  3 |      2 |       2 |
|  4 |      2 |       3 |
|  5 |      3 |       1 |
|  6 |      3 |       3 |
|  7 |      4 |       1 |
|  8 |      5 |       6 |
|  9 |      5 |       7 |
| 10 |      5 |       4 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

What I want is to get every `test` that has `group-one` assigned to it, given it has no other group assigned to it.

```
+--------+-----------+
| testID | testName  |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 | test-one  |
|      4 | test-four |
+--------+-----------+
```

I know that I should use a `LEFT JOIN` and I tried to do:

```
SELECT
    t.id `testID`,
    t.name `testName`
FROM
    tests `t`
INNER JOIN
    testGroupAssignments `tga`
ON
    t.id = tga.testID
LEFT JOIN
    testGroupAssignments `tga2`
ON
    t.id = tga.testID AND tga2.groupID != 1
INNER JOIN
    testGroups `tg`
ON
    tg.id = tga.groupID
WHERE
    tga.groupID = 1
AND
    tga2.groupID != 1
AND
    tga2.groupID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT t.id AS testID, t.name AS testName
FROM tests t
  INNER JOIN testGroupAssignments tga ON t.id = tga.testID
  INNER JOIN testGroups tg ON tg.id = tga.groupID
WHERE tga.groupID = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM testGroupAssignments 
  WHERE testID = t.id AND groupID <> 1
)
```

In case you don't want to show column values of the other tables you can use the following simple query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tests t 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM testGroupAssignments tga 
  WHERE tga.testID = t.id AND tga.groupID = 1
) AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM testGroupAssignments tga 
  WHERE tga.testID = t.id AND tga.groupID <> 1
)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b587888553ff6f34b1607ef2940c39ea)

Comment: This works wonders, is general enough to be usable with different data types. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation with `JOIN` :

```
SELECT ts.id AS testID, ts.name AS testName 
FROM tests ts INNER JOIN
     testGroupAssignments tg
     ON tg.testID = ts.id
GROUP BY ts.id, ts.name
HAVING COUNT(tg.groupID) = 1;
```

If you have a duplicate `groupID`s then use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

use self join to testgroupassigments table try this.

```
SELECT t.id AS Testgroupassignments_id,
test.`name` AS Test_name,
testg.`name` AS Test_group_name
FROM  stackoverflow.testgroupassignments AS t
LEFT JOIN stackoverflow.tests AS test ON test.id = t.testID
LEFT JOIN stackoverflow.testgroups AS testg ON testg.id = t.groupID
WHERE t.id  NOT IN (
SELECT ta.id FROM
stackoverflow.testgroupassignments AS ta
LEFT JOIN  stackoverflow.testgroupassignments AS taa ON taa.testID = ta.testID
WHERE ta.id <> taa.id )
```